# Regular Expressions in Dreamweaver : bug?

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I write `<a(.*\n.*)*` in Search Dreamweaver.

If I use `Ctrl+F` (Find on the current page, with `"Use reg.expr."`)) this selects all from first <a on the page to the end of the page.

Ok, but if I use `Ctrl+Shift+F` ( Find and replace in files, with "Use reg.expr.")  this selects only `<a`.

Is it a bug or I do something wrong ?

Comment: That regex looks like it's gonna suffer from catastrophic backtracking. If you want to match "to the end of the file", you can either just use `.*` with the DOTALL modifier (not sure how DreamWeaver offers that option though) or use a "match everything" sequence such as `[\d\D]*` (ie. "any digit or any non-digit")

Comment: Niet the Dark Absol, thank you for your answer ! It works!